# Creating a file in windows that no other user can access

Tags: windows, security

I'm working on some code which creates files for temporary storage. I've just started using `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` in `CreateFile` to make sure that the files are closed even if the process is killed or crashes. I also use `0` for `dwShareMode`, so (correct me if I'm wrong) that should prevent any other process from accessing the file.

But, what if the entire system crashes? I'm guessing that will leave the file un-deleted when it next starts up. To guard against that, I'd like to create the file so that no other user can access the file (although it would be nice if they could delete it, just to clean up). I haven't been able to find any simple examples for doing something like this (Do I really need to do something as involved as https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446595(v=vs.85).aspx ?)

One other concern I have when doing this is that our code sometimes runs under thread impersonation (when running in the context of a server), so I'm not sure how that would affect things. I just want 'the current user' (either the one who created the process, or the one being impersonated on the current thread) to be the only one who can read/write the file.

Comment: Is setting the delete disposition different than using `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` in CreateFile?

Comment: The user has control of where these files are created, so I wanted to do something sensible even if it was a public directory

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding, you're saying SetInformationByHandle has the same effect as closing a FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE handle? Interesting

Comment: ` you could create it with a empty, protected DACL` how would I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd use SetInformationByHandle then, since I don't necessarily want to prevent the user from opening the swap file themselves

Comment: Yes, it's like closing the handle, but the delete disposition can be toggled, as long as a File is opened with delete access. When the delete disposition is unset, the file becomes accessible again. I don't follow what you mean by the user opening the swap file themselves. You've set the sharing mode to 0, so no other handle can be opened to access the data. Only the metadata (attributes, security) can be accessed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking of changing the sharing mode to be less restrictive.

Comment: Anyway, if the file can be created in a public directory, then at its simplest you can set a security descriptor with an empty, protected DACL. By protected I mean to set the [SD control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379582) to include `SE_DACL_PRESENT | SE_DACL_PROTECTED`, so that it won't inherit from the parent directory. By empty I mean that the [initialized ACL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378853) has no ACEs. This effectively denies all access to other users, but the owner and administrators can always attain access.

Comment: If you want to make it *easy* for the user to open a new handle for the file, assuming you make the sharing less restrictive, then you need to add an ACE that grants full control to the effective user SID, based on the effective token (thread impersonation or process). It would be similar to the [example you linked to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446595), but using the user SID instead of everyone, and also protecting the DACL from inheritance.

Comment: Would using WinCreatorOwnerSid (From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379650(v=vs.85).aspx ) as the only one w/ access work?

Comment: ... does createfile take thread impersonation into account?

Answer (score 0):

why you just create script that run on start-up to delete the file

place the script in startup folder as below, and the script will run during startup only,

Your personal startup folder should be

> C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

The All Users startup folder should be

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

.....